# Calling a php variable on an AJAX processing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, variables

When the user logs in, I store the email in $email (I have also tried global $email). Then I have a form where they type in their roommate's name to search for already scheduled appointments.

AJAX

```
$("#reserveAPickupAppointmentForm3").submit (function() {
    roommate = $("#roommate").val();
    $.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + roommate, function (response) {
    $("#roommateResults").html(response);
    });
return false;
});
```

On roommateSearch.php, if an appointment is found, you can click on the appointment to schedule one for yourself at the same time.  Then I take that information and post it to another processing page at postAppointment.php so that I can insert it in the database.

```
        $(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
            $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
            var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", entry).text();
            var subLocation = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentSubLocation", entry).text();
            var startTime = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime", entry).text();
            var endTime = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime", entry).text();
            var date = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentDate", entry).text();

            alert (location + subLocation + startTime + endTime + date);

            $.post("postAppointment.php", "location=" + location + "subLocation=" + subLocation + "startTime=" + startTime + "endTime=" + endTime + "date=" + date, function (response) {
                alert (response);
            });
        });
```

In order to create the appointment correctly, though, I need to recapture the user's email and add it to the SQL statement.  But, when I call $email on postAppointment.php, nothing shows up.  How would I do this?

I have flirted with the idea of including it on the original form as a hidden input textbox with $email as the value, then passing that info with the rest of it, but surely there is an easier way...I'm hoping there is a way to get postAppointment.php to recognize $email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user succesfully logs in, Keep his email id in a session variable. You can access this variable value in your ajax processing page.

Check whether you have added "`php session_start()`" in the page where you are accesssing session variable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this does not seem to work, and just shows up blank in the response.  $_SESSION["email"] DOES work in the main page's php

Comment: Once you set session , you should be able to access that in other PHP pages. Did you add php session_start() on top of the page where you try to access ?

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that I needed session_start on every page where I use it...If I am understanding you correctly, I would need to do this?  I guess I figured once the session was started on the first, I didn't need to do that.  So far all of my pages have been included with the exception of roommateResults.php and postAppointment.php, so  can see why I wouldn't have needed to do that yet.

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much, I had tried so many things over the last two days, I knew I was missing something simple.  I appreciate you going over something so basic with me!

Answer (score 1):

Sessions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: So i use sessons, I have the variable saved in $_SESSION['email'] as well, but that does not work either (i will try this again right now to double check, but I'm pretty sure i tried it before)

Comment: yes I just double checked this, and it is still appearing blank.  $_SESSION["email"] works in the main php on the page.

Comment: Ah, it turns out I wasn't reopening my session on the processing page. Your solutions work, but I have marked the answer above correct because it mentions the forgotten session_start(). Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Is $email declared on the same script??

Else, you can use a **session variable**, start a session and store the variable in a session,

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
```

if this is a real system then know that session is not always secure, there are many problems such session fixation, session hijacking, so take security measures with session

Also, you can also use **Cookies**, when the user logs in, set a cookie

```
setCookie("email",$email);
```

then get the Cookie, `$getEmail=$_COOKIE['email']`

Comment: setting the session dos not seem to work for me, as $_SESSION["email"] is working in the main body of the page, but returns blank in the AJAX.  Cookies are a great suggestion, I think I will try this next.  I will let you know how it goes

Comment: Ah, it turns out I wasn't reopening my session on the processing page.  Your solutions work, but I have marked the answer above correct because it mentions the forgotten session_start().  Thanks so much for your time!